# multiplying two large integers using an addition method and appending zeroes

Tags: java, class, append, multiplication, addition

So I'm trying to write a multiplication method that multiplies two large positive integers using an addition method (already pre-written within the class). My biggest issue right now is figuring out how to append zeroes to the end using my helper method (which adds the first number a set of number of times from 0-9 (for example 12*6 would add 12 six times). Once I get that value I want to add it to 12*2, which should be appended with a zero (like elementary school multiplication more or less). I drew arrows pertaining to the methods in question. Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

```
  12
x 26
----
  72
 240 <- how to append this zero?
----
 312
```

Here's my class:

```
public class BigNum {

// F i e l d s

private String num;  // Representation of our number

// C o n s t r u c t o r s

/** Constructs a <tt>BigNum</tt> from a non-empty String of digits.
 *  @param num The string to be interpreted.
 *  @throws IllegalArgumentException if num is length zero or
 *      has any non-numeric digits
 *  @throws NullPointerException if num is null
 */
public BigNum(String num) {
    for (int i=0; i<num.length(); i++) {
        if ( ! Character.isDigit(num.charAt(i)) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    if ( num.length() == 0 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.num = num;
}

/** Constructs a <tt>BigNum</tt> from a non-negative integer.
 *  @param num The non-negative integer to be interpreted.
 *  @throws IllegalArgumentException if num is negative
 */
public BigNum(int num) {
    // If num<0, redirected constructor will throw exception due to "-"
    this(""+num);
    if(num < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    //this(""+num);
}

/** Constructs a <tt>BigNum</tt> with value zero.
 */
public BigNum() {
    num="0";
}

// P u b l i c   M e t h o d s

/** Adds two <tt>BigNum</tt> objects' values together and returns a new
  * <tt>BigNum</tt> object with the resulting value.
  *
  * @param other this and other objects get added together
  * @return a new BigNum with the resulting value
  */
public BigNum add(BigNum other) {
    // Make shorter refer to the shorter num, longer to the longer num
    String shorter = other.num;
    String longer = this.num;
    if (this.num.length() < other.num.length()) {
        shorter = this.num;
        longer = other.num;
    }
    // Prepend zeros to make shorter as long as longer
    while (shorter.length() < longer.length()) {
        shorter = "0" + shorter;
    }
    // Add columns like we did in grade school
    int carry = 0;
    String result = "";
    for (int i=shorter.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        int temp = Character.getNumericValue(shorter.charAt(i)) +
                   Character.getNumericValue(longer.charAt(i)) + carry;
        result = (temp%10)+result;
        carry = temp/10;
    }
    // Handle carry-out, if there is one. Return result
    if (carry == 1) {
        result = "1"+result;
    }
    return new BigNum(result);
}

/**Multiplies two <tt>BigNum<tt> values together and returns a new
  *<tt>BigNum<tt> object with the resulting value.
  *
  *@param other
  *@returns a new BigNum with resulting value
  */
public BigNum mult(BigNum other) { //<---------------------Method in question
  BigNum result = new BigNum();
  String s = "";
  int current = 0;
  for(int i=0; i < this.num.toString().length();i++) {
     current += Character.getNumericValue(this.num.charAt(i));
     result = mult(current,other);
     s = result.toString();
   int count=0;
   for(int j=0; j < count; j++) {
        s += "0";
        count++;
   }
  }
   return new BigNum(s); 
}

/**Helper method that adds the other value a set of number of times, 0-9
  *
  *@param and int n and other object
  *@returns resulting value
  */
public BigNum mult(int n, BigNum other) { //<---------------Method in question
     BigNum result = new BigNum();
     for(int i=0;i < n;i++) {
        result=result.add(other);
     }
     return result;
}

/**Compares the other object with another value and only returns true if 
  *the value is less than the object the value.
  *
  *@param other
  *@return true or false
  */

public boolean less(BigNum other) {
    String shorter = other.num;
    String longer = this.num;
     if(other.toString().length() > this.toString().length()) {
        return true;
     }
     else if(other.toString().length() == this.toString().length()){
        for(int i=0; i < other.toString().length();i++) {
           if(Character.getNumericValue(shorter.charAt(i)) > Character.getNumericValue(longer.charAt(i))){
              return true;
           }
        }

     }
     return false;
}

/** Returns a string representation of the number. No leading zeros
  * will exist unless the overall value is zero.
  *
  * @return String representation of the BigNum
  */
public String toString() {
    return num;
}

/** Used only for unit testing. When run, should output only trues. */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Test constructors
    BigNum test = new BigNum("123");
    System.out.println(test.toString().equals("123"));
    test = new BigNum(123);
    System.out.println(test.toString().equals("123"));
    test = new BigNum();
    System.out.println(test.toString().equals("0"));
    // Test addition
    BigNum a = new BigNum();
    BigNum b = new BigNum();
    BigNum c = a.add(b);
    System.out.println(c.toString().equals("0"));
    a = new BigNum("999");
    b = new BigNum("101");
    c = a.add(b);
    System.out.println(c.toString().equals("1100"));
    a = new BigNum("237468273643278");
    b = new BigNum("87326487236437826");
    c = a.add(b);
    System.out.println(c.toString().equals("87563955510081104"));
    //Test multiplication
    BigNum j = new BigNum();
    BigNum k = new BigNum();
    BigNum l = j.mult(k);
    j = new BigNum("111");
    k = new BigNum("3");        
    l =j.mult(k);
    System.out.println(l.toString());
    System.out.println(j.less(k));

}
```

}

Comment: Is the entire code pertinent to your question? The general solution for appending a 0 to the right side of a number is to multiply it by 10...

Comment: Probably not but it couldn't hurt. As for the solution how exactly would I get it to append after the second multiplication/iteration, I thought about using a for loop but I couldn't figure out where to begin or place it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first number with every single char in the second number and then multiply the result again with 10 (or depending on its position i.e. 10 for tens position, 100 for hundreds position and so on) for appending zeroes.